How to create multi user on session xrdp with ubuntu
I want to create a server that allows multiple users to view the same desktop so they can have control while I can also exhibit control. I want to be able to watch things with other people but most streaming solutions are not that great, this would also allow me to view it on my tv without having to cast to it from my main pc.
I have tried xrdp but for some reason I see others getting multi user same session to work, but everything I have tried does not seem to work.
I don't really know where to start in terms of what information to give, I am quite new to linux. Any advice would be helpful, thanks in advance.

Prior to Ubuntu 16.04 I was able to do this.  Since then, it seems only only 1 can be logged into an ID at a time.  As of 22.04, if you log into an ID which is currently logged on, the previous screen is knocked out and your log-in takes it's place.

Interesting, Would switching to Ubuntu 16.04 give me that ability or would there be some kind of security risk involved with doing so. Also I wonder if it has something to do with gnome since XRDP uses Gnomes GUI. Maybe there is some kind of configuration there that I am not seeing?

Aw man. That stinks, well I will give it a shot anyways since there doesn't seem to be a solution on newer versions of Ubuntu, I will be okay as long as it can run Firefox. Thanks for the info, I at the least have something to try again instead of just scratching my head looking at the same ini file for 5 hours. Thanks again for the comment ^_^.

Years of security patches will not be applied if you install a long EOL version ie 16.04 and there is no support for old versions like this.
